# Meteor.js adding more info on user account sign up

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor

Below is my code, but for some reason the first and last names aren't saved? How do I save additional info when creating a new user in Meteor? I'm using the accounts-password package.

```
Accounts.createUser({
  email: email,
  password : password,
  profile: {firstName: firstName, lastName: lastName}
}, function (err) {
  if (err) {
    // Inform the user that account creation failed
  } else {
    // Success. Account has been created and the user
    // has logged in successfully. 
  }
});
```

Comment: Do you have any call to `Accounts.onCreateUser`?

Comment: Yes. I commented it out and now it's working fine. This was the onCreateUser code: `Accounts.onCreateUser(function (options, user) {
  if (!user.username && !user.services && !user.services.facebook) {
    user.username = user.services.facebook.username;
  }

  return user;
});`
Why did that cause a problem with profile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `onCreateUser` callback should return the finall `user` object which is about to be saved into the database. The problem you have comes from the fact that the `profile` data need to be hooked manually tho the `user` object
(see [meteor docs](http://docs.meteor.com/#accounts_oncreateuser) for more details):

```
Accounts.onCreateUser(function(options, user) {
    // [...]
    if (options.profile)
        user.profile = options.profile;
    return user;
});
```